# Node.js - Validate if age is under 18 while using "personnummer.js"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that checks if a [Swedish Personal Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identity_number_(Sweden)) (similiar to Social Security number) is valid or not using [personnummer.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/personnummer.js).

My code looks like this:

```js
const Personnummer = require("personnummer.js");

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {

    const ssn = req.query?.ssn || req.body?.personal_number;

    const error = {
        message: 'Personnumber is rquired',
        name: 'BadRequest' 
    };

    if (!ssn) {
        return next(new NotFoundError(error, 403));
    }

    const valid = Personnummer.validate(ssn);

    //to get age, we can use Personnummer.parse(ssn).age;

    if (!valid) {
        error.message = 'Invalid ssn';
    }

    return valid ? next() : next(new NotFoundError(error, 403));
}
```

and

```
const Personnummer = require("personnummer.js");

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const ssn = req.query?.ssn || req.body?.ssn;

        if (!ssn) {
            return res.json({valid: false, message: 'Personnumer is required'});
        }

        const valid = Personnummer.validate(ssn);

        const response = {
            valid,
            message: valid ? 'Valid personnumer' : 'Invalid personnumer'
        }

        return res.json(response);

    } catch(err) {
        next(err);
    }
}
```

How can I make it so Personal Number is also invalid if the age is under 18 years old?

To determine the age from the personal number, we can use `Personnummer.parse(ssn).age` that gives the age as `int`.

Comment: What is the question? You seem to have all the information needed with "*we can use Personnummer.parse(ssn).age*"

Comment: Seems your question is more about how to validate the user's age, rather than how to use personnummer

Comment: I rewrote the question. yes, i would like the system to make personnummer invalid when the age is under 18 years old.

Comment: So you're looking for a simple `age < 18`? Or what do you mean by "make personnummer invalid"?

Comment: `const valid = Personnummer.validate(ssn) && Personnummer.parse(ssn).age >= 18;` seems to fit your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Just check booth and adjust the `return`:

```
const valid = Personnummer.validate(ssn);
const age = Personnummer.parse(ssn).age;

if (!valid || age < 18) {
    error.message = 'Invalid personal number or age is under 18';
    return next(new NotFoundError(error, 403));
}

return next();
```

You can also separate results:

```
const valid = Personnummer.validate(ssn);

if (!valid) {
    return res.status(400).json({ valid: false, message: 'Invalid personal number' });
}

const age = Personnummer.parse(ssn).age;

if (age < 18) {
    return res.status(400).json({ valid: false, message: 'Age is under 18' });
}

return res.json({ valid: true, message: 'Valid personal number' });
```

Comment: Thanks, how to handle in this part:
```
const Personnummer = require("personnummer.js");

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {

    try {

        const ssn = req.query?.ssn || req.body?.ssn;

        if (!ssn) {
            return res.json({valid: false, message: 'Personnumer is required'});
        }

        const valid = Personnummer.validate(ssn);

        const response = {
            valid,
            message: valid ? 'Valid personnumer' : 'Invalid personnumer'
        }

        return res.json(response);

    } catch(err) {
        next(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question, comments are not well formatted.

Comment: Updated the question, thank you very much.

Comment: Updated my answer, good luck!